# Add only to negative entries in a vector

Tags: r

I would like to take a vector, for example:

```
X <-  c(1,2,3,-1,-2,-3)
```

and add 1 (or any other number fixed in advance) to the entries in which the values are negative, to produce

```
1,2,3,0,-1,-2
```

Is there a slick way to do this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Submitted in the R Golf competition for this problem:

```
X+(X<0)
```

Works because (X<0) will get coerced 1 for any desired case and 0 for others.

Comment: At 7 characters, this is the shortest solution yet, and will be hard to beat. +1

Comment: Thanks Josh. I passed over that part in my haste to post this beauty.

Answer (score 7):

use `ifelse`:

```
x + ifelse(x<0, 1, 0)
[1]  1  2  3  0 -1 -2
```

Answer (score 7):

An alternative that is vectorised but slightly more verbose is:

```
> X <-  c(1,2,3,-1,-2,-3)
> want <- X < 0
> X[want] <- X[want] + 1
> X
[1]  1  2  3  0 -1 -2
```

The key step is to generate indices where X is negative (`want`). We then use this to index `X` and add 1 to these only.

Whether the vectorisation outweighs the number of function calls involved above I leave to others to discuss (I doubt it make any difference for most problems).

Comment: I usually use `x[x < 0] <- x[x < 0] + 1`, just to save lines of code, but is the same.

Comment: +1 I considered that but decided doing the comparison twice might be costly for some problems. Again, for most data sets I doubt differences between methods are great.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps not the most readable solution, but I'll still post it for the fun of it:

```
> pmax(X, X+sign(X)*(-1))
[1]  1  2  3  0 -1 -2
```

Comment: I like the use of sign(X) and the pmax selection strategy is cute.

Answer (score 0):

One can use which command also :

```
X <-  c(1,2,3,-1,-2,-3)
X[which(X < 0)] <- X[which(X < 0)] +1
```

Comment: In this case, `which` is unnecessary, and therefore redundant.